# Start up applications in different workspaces

Tags: workspaces, startup-applications

I want to start some applications when I turn on my computer.

For example, open Sublime in workspace 1 and Chrome in workspace 2 and so on.

I know how to use startup applications in Ubuntu but I have no idea about open them in different workspaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try gDevilspie**

*gDevilspie is a graphical front-end for editing the Devilspie configuration file which allows you to run a particular application within a particular way.*

Install gdevilspie : `sudo apt-get install gdevilspie`

[image]